# Trouble deleting file from tracking using Git

Tags: git

I have a weird problem with untracking file.
I have a tracked file `index.css`. Then I add it to `.gitignore`. Then I run the following and get an output:

```
$ git rm --cached build/development/css/index.css
rm 'build/development/css/index.css'
```

Running `git status` gives the following:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    build/development/css/index.css
```

When try to commit changes I get the following error:

```
Error:On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
 during executing git commit --only -F C:\Users\dtv\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-7154374096157077481.txt -- build/development/css/index.css
```

If I try to commit the changes to `index.css` along with outher changes, the commit goes without error. But changes to the file is still detected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue with git version 1.9. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Zeeker, 1.9.4. There is something wrong with this file. I can't figure out what. Any steps I can take to track it down?

Comment: Not really, but maybe something in your repository broke. You can always try to reclone the repository and try again.

Comment: Just cloned the repository again. Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `--only` option for `git commit`. From `git-commit` manpage:

> Make a commit only from the paths specified on the command line,
>   disregarding any contents that have been staged so far.

It tries to commit that file, disregarding the previous `git rm --cached` command from before.

Answer (score 1):

- as per my observation, if we use this `git rm --cached filename` command it ignores on that time only.
- if you add that file in **.gitignore**, git ignores(untracks) that file permanently. After adding filename or path to **.gitignore** we have to execute the following commands to untrack those files from next time onwards

  First commit any outstanding code changes, and then, run the following command

  `git rm -r --cached .` -> This removes any changed files from the index(staging area)

  `git add .`

  `git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"` -> to commit the changes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

**git update-index --assume-unchanged path_to_file**

This will mark the file in the index and git will stop tracking the file for any modifications. In combination with adding this file in **.gitignore** it will stop showing it as modified when using

**git status**

You can also check the docs for [update-index](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html)